# Where i have to place the .cfg.xml and .hbm.xml files with hibernate configurations?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

In a project with the tree below, where i have to place these files?

```
src
|_ com
   |_ app
      |_ java
      |  |_ controllers
      |  |_ models
      |_ webapp
         |_ WEB-INF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside src. Same level as com.